# JavaScript chaining function / function extends using IIFE expression

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, function, chaining

I've been looking for a way of extending a function in a straightforward way, like in [C# extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

I've tried the following statement which I have found in this article [Method Chaining in JavaScript](https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html) and which works fine.

```
var FOO = function(){
     this.whateverFunc = function(){
         console.log("whatever func");
     }
};
FOO.prototype.first = function(){
     console.log("first func");   
     return this;  
};
FOO.prototype.second = function(){
     console.log("second func");   
     return this;  
};
```

Then I can chain it:

```
 var foo = new FOO();
 foo.first().second();
 //Output
 //first func
 //second func
```

BUT: My projects has the following "pattern":

```
var FOO = (function(){
    var foo{
        firstFunc: function(){
            //implement
        },
        secondFunc: function(){
            //implement
        },
    }
    return foo;
}());
```

It doesn't work even if I don't use IIFE.

```
 var FOO = function() { var foo{}; return foo; };
```

Is there a way to use chaining function within that pattern? How could I accomplish this(if this is possible!):

```
FOO.first().second();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue with the code following

> BUT: My projects has the following "pattern":

is missing `=` at `foo` declaration.

If IIFE uses arrow function the invoking parentheses should be last part of IIFE, instead of within outer parentheses.

```js
var FOO = (function() {
  var foo = {
    firstFunc: function() {
      //implement
      console.log(1);
      return this
    },
    secondFunc: function() {
      //implement
      console.log(2);
      return this
    }
  }
  return foo;
})();

FOO.firstFunc().secondFunc()
```

Comment: You're right, and I didn't know which that is possible with IIFE, just returning "this" and it can be chained, Great. thank you a lot;